# What are the French equivalents to "sea resort"?

Tags: vocabulaire, vacances

So I was working on the Theme: Vacations/Holidays and I first encountered the word: *la station de ski* which can be translated as a "ski resort" in English. Alright. Then I thought about how could one translate a "sea resort" in French and I guessed that it should be "la station de mer," however it turns out that a sea resort is actually *la station balnéaire* in French. Considering this, I would like to know whether my version ("la station de mer") is still correct or not?

Answer (score 5):

The right and established expression is indeed ***Station balnéaire***. No native speaker would say *une station de mer* but you'll probably be understood as it is grammatically correct.

A quick google search shows this expression appears sporadically and is perfectly understandable in a suitable context.

e.g.:

http://www.linkscom.fr/clients/evenements/trophee-mer-montagne

> Cet événement unique a été inventé en 1994 par le navigateur alpiniste Eric Loizeau et rassemble chaque année dans **une station de mer** ou de montagne les acteurs célèbres de ses deux milieux de prédilection pour 4 jours de compétitions intenses et conviviales.

https://gozogetaway.com/fr/towns-beaches/

> Marsalforn est un village de pêcheurs sur la côte nord et est **la station de mer** la plus populaire et développée de Gozo.

http://voyageforum.com/discussion/conseils-jeunes-benidorm-en-aout-2006-espagne-d496745/

> Benidorm est **une station de mer** très vivante et il y a beaucoup de jeunesse.

Comment: I honestly don't think I would understand it on first reading, depending of the context. I would think it's something that's in the sea, like an offshore petrol platform or something. Just use the correct words.

Comment: The words are correct, the wording is (almost) unused. I do not question the fact *station balnéaire* is the right answer. Answer updated to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

"Une station de mer" n'existe pas.
On dit en effet "une station balnéaire".